# Listando todas as categorias com o número total de produtos

Tags: php, mysqli

Preciso montar uma query que exiba o nome de todas as categorias, e na frente de cada nome conste o número total de produtos.

As tabelas são:

```
 Categorias (cat_codigo, cat_nome)
 Produtos (pro_codigo, pro_codigo_categoria pro_nome)      

 Exemplo:

 Parafusos (58)
 Brocas (42)
 Chaves (33)
```

Sei fazer as ligações entre as duas tabelas, mas estou na dúvida sobre obter a quantidade total:

```
 select * from categorias CAT LEFT JOIN produtos PRO ON CAT.cat_codigo=PRO.pro_codigo_categoria
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select  count(PRO.pro_nome), CAT.cat_nome
 from categorias CAT
 INNER JOIN 
   produtos PRO ON CAT.cat_codigo=PRO.pro_codigo_categoria
 group by CAT.cat_nome
```

Vai te listar a quantidade de produtos para cada categoria.

Comment: muito obrigado! é isso mesmo.

Comment: Por nada heheh !

Comment: Se possível marca como solução que ai fica marcado como resolvido... abraços.